# wxErlang Method for getting screen dimensions

Tags: windows, windows-xp, wxerlang

I am starting to play with wxErlang on XP, and am looking for a method of getting the screens dimension, so that I can cause my app to be drawn on the lower right hand corner of the screen.  The wxErlang documentation seems to have an undue number of references to the wxWidgets c++ external documentation.

After Googling for a bit I ended up [here](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/group__group__funcmacro__gdi.html#gb8a48ec2fc13c5112ff5fcd42e2881b9), which seems to describe what I am looking for.

```
void wxClientDisplayRect
(    
    int *   x,
    int *   y, 
    int *   width, 
    int *   height  
);
```

*Returns the dimensions of the work area on the display.
On Windows this means the area not covered by the taskbar, etc. Other platforms are currently defaulting to the whole display until a way is found to provide this info for all window managers, etc.
Include file:*

```
#include <wx/gdicmn.h>
```

After searching the wxErlang doc, I haven't found anything corresponding to this function, nor recognized any hint of what should be used.

**How does one get the screen dimensions, using wxErlang, so the window being drawn, can be set to the lower right hand corner of the screen?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done, hence it is a good reason to not use it.